# Formatting Cell in a generated Word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am generating invoices from within my LightSwitch billing application, and after an invoice is generated, the SubTotal, SalesTax and Total Due cells in the Word document are not of the correct format.

I have gone through every single menu option, and explored other *possible* ways to have it formatted before it gets put in the document's Content control, but I just can't get the right format.

The numbers are being displayed as `4100.0000`, but they should be like `4,100.00` or at least like `4100.00`.

How can this be done?

I realise that this is borderline off-topic, but I figured I'd post here anyway *as I believe the solution involves writing code, as opposed to using Word to accomplish this, because I have gone through all the options, and there just doesn't seem to be an option in there to change formatting for a single cell.*

[image]

As requested, code for document generation:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Extensions;
using OfficeIntegration;
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class Billing
    {
        partial void GenerateInvoice_Execute()
        {
            var mappings = new List<ColumnMapping>();

            mappings.Add(new ColumnMapping("InvoiceId", "InvoiceId"));
            mappings.Add(new ColumnMapping("DateGenerated", "DateGenerated"));

            mappings.Add(new ColumnMapping("InvoiceDataGridSubTotal", "SubTotal"));
            mappings.Add(new ColumnMapping("InvoiceDataGridSalesTax", "Tax"));
            mappings.Add(new ColumnMapping("InvoiceDataGridDateDue", "DateDue"));
            mappings.Add(new ColumnMapping("InvoiceDataGridTotalDue", "Total"));

            object doc;
            string path = @"C:\Users\Jason\Documents\SV Invoice.docx";

            doc = OfficeIntegration.Word.GenerateDocument(path, this.BillingTables.SelectedItem, mappings);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you write the numbers into these cells.

Comment: The applpication auto-populates the cells in the word document. But when I enter the numbers into my lightswitch application, I **always** enter them as `4,100.00`. And when I don't, the Lightswitch app auto-formats them anyway - so they should be coming up in the Word document with the correct formatting, I would assume.

Comment: What do you mean with "auto-populate"? Please show the code.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: added full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to supply a third parameter to the `ColumnMapping` constructor: A delegate that formats the values:

```
Func<decimal, string> formatDelegate = x => x.ToString("c2");
mappings.Add(new ColumnMapping("InvoiceDataGridSubTotal", "SubTotal",
                               FormatDelegate: formatDelegate));
```

Comment: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type.`, says Intellisense.

Comment: `The name 'Format' does not exist in the current context.` re: the update.

Comment: @Iateyourtoothpaste: What about the new version?

Comment: sorry, it does not produce errors *but it doesn't display the number anymore. It simply outputs the following text to the word document:* System.Func`2[System.Decimal,System.String]

Comment: Could you please show me which parameters the ColumnMapping constructor has? And please try the new version... BTW: I am currently getting my info from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/07/18/new-and-improved-office-integration-pack-extension-for-lightswitch.aspx - Point 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It led me down the right path to figuring out how to format them - and I also learned how to use delegates lol - I've managed to solve the issue; I just wrote an answer. RE: Params for the ColumnMapping constructor: `ColumnMapping.ColumnMapping(string OfficeColumnName, List<FieldDefinition> TableFields)` and also `ColumnMapping.ColumnMapping(string OfficeColumnName, string EntityFieldName, [objectStaticValue = null], [Delegate FormatDelegate = null])`

Comment: @Iateyourtoothpaste: Thanks for the parameters of the constructor. My latest version should work than. But your approach is the way to go for simple formattings.

Answer (score 2):

Code and Word formatting are unnecessary in this case. In order to have your numbers correctly formatted in the dynamically-generated Word document, you must set the Format to use from within the Data Designer in Visual Studio LightSwitch:

- Open your LightSwitch Project
- Expand the Project Node > Open a `Table` containing a number you'd like to format
- Select the `Field` that requires formatting
- In the `Properties` pane, scroll down until you see Formatting (`Format Pattern`)
- Now here's where you format your numbers. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh674024.aspx#numeric) link for your available options. I chose to format using `C2`.

Following the above steps, I was able to generate a Word document with the following format for money:

`4500.00` instead of `4500.0000`.